# How to uninstall teamviewer 7 -- package doesn't appear in the software center

Tags: networking

I previously installed teamviewer 7 on my Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit system.

However, now I'd like to uninstall it, and I don't see an easy way to do it. 
Normally, I'd look in the Ubuntu software center, but in this case the program isn't there.

How can I uninstall it?

Answer (score 18):

If you installed it with a deb package, you can uninstall it from Synaptics.
Or try this command

`sudo apt-get remove teamviewer*`

Comment: This command seems to remove everything which name starts with "teamviewer", but I have -somehow- installed both teamviewer7 and teamviewer8, I need to ONLY remove 7. Will this remove 7 and keep 8? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever tried following command?
`sudo apt-get remove teamviewer7`
I wrote my answer in order to help any people who need to remove any version of teamviewer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get remove teamviewer
```

The Output will be

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
bluez-alsa:i386 glib-networking:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer0.10-x:i386 gtk2-engines:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 ia32-libs ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 ibus-gtk:i386 lib32asound2 lib32z1 libaa1:i386
libaio1:i386 libao-common libao4:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libaudiofile1:i386 libavc1394-0:i386 libc6-i386
libcaca0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libcanberra0:i386 libcapi20-3:i386
 libcroco3:i386 libcupsfilters1:i386 libcupsimage2:i386 libcurl3:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libdv4:i386 libesd0:i386 libexif12:i386
 libgail-common:i386 libgail18:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libgd2-xpm:i386 libgdbm3:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgettextpo0:i386
 libgnome-keyring0:i386 libgphoto2-2:i386 libgphoto2-port0:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libgudev-1.0-0:i386
 libharfbuzz0:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386
 libibus-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libjasper1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
 libltdl7:i386 libmad0:i386 libmikmod2:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386 libodbc1:i386 libopenal1:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386
 libpixman-1-0:i386 libproxy1:i386 libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386 libpulsedsp:i386 libqt4-designer:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 libqt4-svg:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 librsvg2-2:i386 librsvg2-common:i386
 librtmp0:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsdl-image1.2:i386 libsdl-mixer1.2:i386 libsdl-net1.2:i386
 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libshout3:i386 libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386 libspeex1:i386 libssl0.9.8:i386
 libstdc++5:i386 libtag1-vanilla:i386 libtag1c2a:i386 libtdb1:i386 libunistring0:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386
 libv4lconvert0:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 libwavpack1:i386 libwebp4:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libxaw7:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxft2:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxp6:i386 libxpm4:i386
 libxrandr2:i386 libxtst6:i386 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 odbcinst1debian2:i386 xaw3dg:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
teamviewer
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 81.9 MB disk space will be freed.
```

**Do you want to continue [Y/n]?**

Press **Y** to remove teamviewer

Answer (score 1):

I've uninstalled successfully Teamviewer 7 on Ubuntu 11.10 using Synaptic.
From Terminal to start Synaptic by typing 

`sudo synaptic`

or Menu `System > Administration` , select `Synaptic Package Manager`.

Using `Search` to find teamviewer item in your system, and then marking `Completely removal`.

I hope this tip is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes

```
sudo apt-get remove teamviewer7
```

will not work. 
This command will only work if you used apt-get to install it also, and of course if you installed teamviewer7 and not another version.

For this first find out where teamviewer is loaded / install by `which` command.  Then using the su/sudo prefix, remove both the link file as well as the teamviewer directory and using ubuntu tweak the entries can be removed. This is another way to uninstall the application.